# Determining the state of a process

Tags: java

I am creating a chatbot-like application and I need to know when the application has reached a certain state.

Currently I am using strings to find out what the topic of the conversation is.

Such as

```
String usersaid = text.toString();
if (usersaid.contains("topic-relevant word") {
    execStateRelevantMethod();
}
```

However I'd like to know if there's a more reliable way to do this. Such as:

```
if (usersaid.contains("what time is it") {
    state.set(timeQuery);
}
if (state == timeQuery) {
    execStateRelevantMethod();
}
```

I have made those state commands up to show you what I'm meaning to ask.

Comment: Do you want to detect certain topics of conversation, or just some basic commands (like /time, /topic, whatever) ?

Comment: what is use of it? from this what kind of app state means?

Comment: @answer 2, at certain times strings start getting unreliable. i want something like a boolean but something that can be set to anything, not just true and false.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an enum. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html